# Merge .swiftmodule fails with segmentation fault

Tags: xcode, swift, module, swift2, xcodebuild

`xcodebuild` fails with the following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: merge-module command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    MergeSwiftModule normal arm64 /Users/vmanot/Documents/Xcode/Projects/Frameworks/ExSwift/build/ExSwift.build/Release-iphoneos/ExSwift.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ExSwift.swiftmodule
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)
```

(The `ExSwift` mentioned above is not the the open-source [ExSwift](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift), but a private framework).

The stack trace:

```
0  swift                    0x0000000104229edb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x000000010422a61b SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8e88152a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5d8c0070 _sigtramp + 3473140576
4  swift                    0x000000010268b19e swift::serialization::Serializer::writeSubstitutions(llvm::ArrayRef<swift::Substitution>, std::__1::array<unsigned int, 256ul> const&) + 350
5  swift                    0x000000010268a9dc swift::serialization::Serializer::writeNormalConformance(swift::NormalProtocolConformance const*) + 2684
6  swift                    0x000000010269597b swift::serialization::Serializer::writeAllDeclsAndTypes() + 8043
7  swift                    0x0000000102696949 swift::serialization::Serializer::writeAST(llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>) + 2505
8  swift                    0x0000000102698f47 swift::serialization::Serializer::writeToStream(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::SILModule const*, swift::SerializationOptions const&) + 135
9  swift                    0x0000000102699b82 withOutputFile(swift::ASTContext&, llvm::StringRef, llvm::function_ref<void (llvm::raw_ostream&)>) + 226
10 swift                    0x0000000102699a06 swift::serialize(llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::SerializationOptions const&, swift::SILModule const*) + 214
11 swift                    0x000000010233b54b performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 12843
12 swift                    0x000000010233810a frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2682
13 swift                    0x0000000102334797 main + 2247
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff9d9a35ad start + 1
15 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000108 start + 1650838364
```

How can I locate the faulty code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue (only when compiling with Fast[-O] or None[-Onone] optimization levels. If I switch to -Fast, Whole Module Optimization everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the source of this error can vary wildly and depends on the Swift source you have written. I was receiving this error while trying to write extensions for a custom protocol that conforms to UIPickerViewDataSource. Specifically, I was was writing default implementations for `numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_:)` and `pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)`.

I haven't been able to confirm it, but I suspect the error we experienced has to do with Objective-C interoperability. All I know for sure is that moving those implementations from the protocol into the conforming class fixed the error for me.

**edit:** changing the optimization level as Bruno suggested did not help.